# How many 10-digit numbers have at least 2 equal digits

Tags: combinatorics

Please help go solve this question. I tried it solving, by various methods. But nothing gave a positive result.

Comment: How about finding how many 10 digit numbers don't have at least 2 equal digits?

Comment: Whenever you see "at least" in a probability or counting problem, try to calculate the probability of it NOT happening, and that usually will be easier. You are supposed to include the work you have tried as details for your question, so that we don't re-explain things you already know.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor replace the word "*probability*" with the word "*counting*" in that and quantify it with "*usually*" since it isn't always the case.

Comment: You should show us your "various methods" so that we can help.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ten digit number without any equal digits is a permutation of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.

Assuming the first digit cannot be zero, there are $9\times 9!$ such permutations.

In total there are $9\times 10^9$ ten digit numbers so you can easily calculate the probability.